# php progamiticly access static functions

Tags: php, static, static-methods

Which is better and why:

```
call_user_func(array($class, $method), $params);
```

or

```
$class::$method($params);
```

the second approach only works in PHP 5.3. I in older virsion in throws a fatal error unexpected T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM. (my ide thinks its a syntax error, too. But it works)

Comment: My understanding is that both approaches will result in the same effective runtime approach to calling the function, and should perform about the same.

Comment: As soon as your question contains the words "which is better," you should look to http://programmers.stackexchange.com for answers.

Comment: Also, the second only can do methods that take params as an array of items. The first can access methods that take any kind of parameters. Which should be easier to read in the class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well if portability is important for you, then the obvious answer that you should use the first way. If you know that you're always targeting at least PHP 5.3, then you should use the method that you feel most comfortable yourself. The `$class::$method($params);` is shorter and cleaner, so I'd go for it myself.

Answer (score 1):

Both are just fine.  It's my opinion that the second is more syntactically clear, though.  As you stated, the only downside is that it requires 5.3+.

Answer (score 0):

With PHP 5.3.0, there is also the [forward_static_call()](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.forward-static-call.php) function, although there's slightly more restrictions to its use